# Team Foundation Server Build Drop to Server - Content-Type of "" for method type "PUT" which is not supported

Tags: json, visual-studio-2013, tfs, build, msbuild

I have been working on a Build that Drops to TFS Server. Just to contextualize, I'm refering to this option on the build definition:

[Build Definition Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07v2L.png)

Normally, this builds don't have any issue on dropping to the TFS Server. My build only produces Setup Files (InstallShield), however, it fails on the "CopyDirectoryTask" Task with the following error:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets
>   (1565, 0) The request indicated a Content-Type of "" for method type
>   "PUT" which is not supported. Valid content types for this method are:
>   application/json, application/json-patch+json,
>   application/octet-stream.

And more detailed:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets
>   (1565, 0) The "CopyDirectoryTask" task failed unexpectedly.
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssServiceException: The
>   request indicated a Content-Type of "" for method type "PUT" which is
>   not supported. Valid content types for this method are:
>   application/json, application/json-patch+json,
>   application/octet-stream. at
>   System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Invoke(Activity activity,
>   IDictionary`2 inputs, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions,
>   TimeSpan timeout) at System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(Activity
>   workflow, IDictionary`2 inputs, TimeSpan timeout,
>   WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.WorkflowTask.ExecuteInternal() at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.Task.Execute() at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__1.MoveNext()

From what I can understand, there is a problem between the type of Content Type that the server accepts on the call and the one it is sending (that appears to be empty).

Is there a known reason for that? Depends on the build output? (Folders and setup files in my case), never had this issue with other types of builds. I'm starting to think that it could be a server problem, as this process is entirely handled by TFS, I can't change the submit type.

I appreciate any comment or help on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it occur if you create a new build definition? And did you customize the definition activities before?

Comment: Yes, it happens even with a new build definition.

The Definition Activities are pretty much default, no mods there.

Comment: I just try this with an installshield project but didn't see any issue. Does this issue occur with other project? And does it work if you change to "Copy build output to the following drop folder"?

Comment: Just tried with another project (both in the same and different collections and it happens as well. And yes, it works when I chage it to "Copy to the following drop folder.

The only major change we had on our infrastructure was the migration from TFS2013.4 to TFS2015.1

Comment: Does the build server use the same machine with TFS server? If not, is it also been upgraded to TFS2015?

Comment: Thanks a lot Eddie, didn't occur to me that it may be the Build Controller not updated and, in fact, it was not updated. (The others were and since it did compile no one noticed).

Once I updated it it now uploads without a problem. Can you please Answer the Question "officially" so I can mark your response as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: OK, Glad to hear that the problem is resolved. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you performed a migration from TFS2013 to TFS2015, you need to make sure all the related components (Build Controller, Build Agent and so on) on all servers are updated to TFS2015 too.